# How do I create a new iCloud account for my daughter's iPad?

Tags: icloud

Two middle school daughters with new iPads (had to purchase for school). I will keep my AppleID on them for apps and music but want to create their own iCloud accounts for their photos, school work etc. How do I create a new account?

Comment: If @b4d's answer resolved your question, remember to mark it as the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official Apple guide:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2731?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

If you get stuck somewhere in between just ask.